# unable to save files from Code Blocks ONLY

Tags: 12.04, ntfs, code-blocks

i have an NTFS drive mounted in a folder `/Tejas` 
i have created a new project using it in a folder in this drive but i am unable to save the changes, i get the following error message

> Couldn't save project /Tejas/Project/codeblock/ciphers/ciphers.cbp
>   (Maybe the file is write-protected?)

i get similar message even when i try to save the c source file

i am able to edit and save files using gedit editor...
why am i getting this problem?
EDIT:
i have modified my fstab and added this line

> /dev/sda5/Tejas ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,defaults,umask=000 0 0

but it still doesn't seem to work not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this thread](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=t9ro3k0uhci99m7vo238pgss86&/topic,10735.msg73563.html#msg73563) and perhaps can save you from all this.

It is marked as `SOLVED` So it will surely solve your problem.

```
Q. Why I just put link here?
A. It doesn't worth copy and paste things.
```

Edit 1 :
it should be like this,

```
/dev/sda5 /media/Tejas ntfs defaults,uid=YYYY,gid=XXXX,umask=007 0 0
```

`YYYY` your user id, `XXXX`your group id.

create folder `Tejas` if it's not there in `/media/` by issuing

```
sudo mkdir /media/Tejas
```

Edit 2 :
you can try

`/dev/sda5 /media/Tejas   ntfs-3g   defaults,umask=000  0  0`

or

```
/dev/sda5 /media/Tejas ntfs-3g defaults,uid=YYYY,gid=XXXX,umask=007 0 0
```

Comment: is this correct  
`/dev/sda5/Tejas ntfs uid=1000,gid=1000,defaults,umask=000 0 0`

Comment: `/dev/sda5   /media/Tejas   ntfs   defaults,uid=1000,gid=46,umask=007  0  0`

Comment: `uid=` your user id, `gid=` your group id

Comment: create folder `Tejas` if it's not there in `/media/` by issuing `sudo mkdir /media/Tejas`

Comment: all the mounting stuff is working i can access files even create and delete files documents etc... but code blocks says that it cant save files.   
i have put uid and gid from the command "id username"